# Prove two groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-isomorphism, module-isomorphism

I have created the two tables but can not find a one to one correlation between the values in the two tables. I would appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction to understand how to solve this.

```
+4  0   1   2   3  
0   0   1   2   3  
1   1   2   3   4  
2   2   3   0   1  
3   3   4   1   2  

*5  1   2   3   4  
1   1   2   3   4  
2   2   4   1   3  
3   3   1   4   2  
4   4   3   2   1
```

Thank you!

[question 31.3-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK7Sv.png)

Comment: You didn't post an actual question

Comment: It would be very helpful for you to provide the tables of the group, because we could help find a more specific answer

Comment: yes sorry I've added them

Comment: Ok, to start with, what does $0$ correspond to?  and are you familiar with cyclic groups?

Comment: based on the table 0 corresponds to 1 in the *5 table. I am  not familiar with cyclic groups

Comment: correct; do you know what the order of an element is?  orders are preserved by isomorphisms

Comment: yes I understand what an order of an element is

Comment: determine the order of each element in each group

Comment: You have $G=(\{ 0,1,2,3\},+_4)$ and $H=(\{1,2,3,4\},\ast_5)$
If they are isomorphic, then exists a bijective homomorphism $f\colon G\to H$ such that:

$$ f(a+_4b)=f(a)\ast_5f(b) $$

Comment: the order of +4={0,1,2,3} is (1,2,3,3). Order of *5={1,2,3,4} is (1,2,2,2)

Comment: No, the order of $1$ and $3$ in $\Bbb Z_4$ is $4$; the order of $2$ in $\Bbb  Z_4$ is $2$; the order of $2$ and $3$ in $\Bbb Z_5^*$ is $4$; so an isomorphism must map $2$ to $4$

Comment: I see your point. now we have two more that must be mapped but they all have order of 4.

Comment: yes, in fact you could map $1$ to $2$ or $1$ to $3$ (and $3$ to $3$ or $3$ to $2$, respectively) and have an isomorphism

Comment: Thank you very much that is beautiful!

Comment: are you sure the order of Z* of 2 and 3 is 4? because when I do 2^2mod5=4 order is 2

Comment: order in $\Bbb Z_5^*$ of $2$ and $3$ is $4,$ because powers of $2$  are $1,2,4,$ and $3$ and $2^4=16\equiv1,$ and powers of $3$ are $1,3,9\equiv4,$ and $27\equiv2$ and $3^4=81\equiv1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groups are cyclic; that means they are generated by a single element.

A generator of $\Bbb Z_4$ is   $1$; i.e., the elements in $\Bbb Z_4$ are $0, 1, 1+1, $ and $1+1+1$.

A generator of $\Bbb Z_5^*$ is   $2$; i.e., the elements in $\Bbb Z_5^*$ are $1, 2, 2^2, 2^3\equiv_53.  $

The map from $\Bbb Z_4$ to $\Bbb Z_5^*$ that takes $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$, $1+1$ to $2\times2$, and $1+1+1$ to $2^3\equiv_5 3$

is an isomorphism.

To prove that from scratch, you would have to verify $16$ statements

(actually only $10$ if you use commutativity).